# PHP Associative Array inside SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have an associative $date array

```
Array ( [June 2019] => 2019-06-01 [July 2019] => 2019-07-01 [August 2019] => 2019-08-01 [September 2019] => 2019-09-01 [January 2020] => 2020-01-01 [January 2021] => 2021-01-01 [June 2021] => 2021-06-01 [August 2021] => 2021-08-01 [October 2021] => 2021-10-01 [April 2022] => 2022-04-01 )
```

I'd like to run a Mysql query for each element of this array while using key/value inside the query.
I think SQL doesn't recognize those values for some reason and nothing is returned.

```
foreach($date as $month => $actual_date) {
$query = "select user, score, @month := $month as month from table where drop_date > '$actual_date' AND drop_date <= date_add('$actual_date', INTERVAL 1 YEAR)";
```

Comment: You don't have quotes around your `$month` variable.

Comment: It's easier to debug SQL by looking at the SQL, instead of looking at PHP code that is supposed to generate SQL. Log the resultant `$query` string after you interpolate variables into it.

Comment: @mark_b Thanks , indeed it was a variable inside a query without quotation.

Comment: I know it gets touted a lot round here, and your data may well have come from a safe source, but using prepared statements by default will eliminate errors such as these.